# How do I create a angular directive/service for very simple pagination with only next/prev options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

there is a block of div tags on which ng-repeat is being run. I have to show a stack of 3 such divs at a time. On clicking next the next 3 set of divs should be shown and same with previous click button

Here is the HTML

```
<div ng-click="">next</div>
<div ng-click="">prev</div>
<div ng-repeat="event in events" ng-hide="$index>2"> 
<div class="event-description">{{event.description}}</div> 
<span class="event-time">{{event.time}}</span> 
<span class="event-product">{{event.product}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post any HTML code?

Comment: <div ng-click="">next</div>
<div ng-click="">prev</div>
<div ng-repeat="event in events" ng-hide="$index>2"> 
<div class="event-description">{{event.description}}</div> 
<span class="event-time">{{event.time}}</span> 
<span class="event-product">{{event.product}}</span>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can implement something like this:

```
$scope.hiddenIndex = 0;

$scope.next = function() {
    $scope.hiddenIndex += 3;
    if ($scope.hiddenIndex >= $scope.events.length) {
        $scope.hiddenIndex = 0;
    }
};
```

and use it in HTML this way:

```html
<div ng-repeat="event in events" 
     ng-hide="$index < hiddenIndex || $index >= hiddenIndex + 3">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/PuMBWbW1IGDV8u1x4HFZ?p=preview